# MySQL Show recommended items

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a news system where users can recommend the item. But now I want that when someone is viewing an item, display a list of other items that have been recommended by people who recommended the item is viewed. Something like "Users who recommended this item also recommended..."

Recommendations table

```
  +----+------+---------+
  | id | user |   item  |
  +----+------+---------+
  | 1  |   1  |    1    | User 1 recommended item 1
  +----+------+---------+
  | 2  |   1  |    2    |
  +----+------+---------+
  | 3  |   2  |    2    |
  +----+------+---------+
  | 4  |   3  |    3    |
  +----+------+---------+
  | 5  |   2  |    3    |
  +----+------+---------+
```

Items  table

```
  +----+---------+---------+
  | id |  title  | author  |
  +----+---------+---------+
  | 1  |Hello... |    me   |
  +----+---------+---------+
  | 2  | Bye...  |   you   |
  +----+---------+---------+
  | 3  |  Hi...  |    me   |
  +----+---------+---------+
```

As you can see the user with ID 1, recommended item 1 and 2 and User 2 also recommended item 2, also recommended item 3.
So when someone is looking at item 2, should be displayed in the list the item 3.
Also when someone is watching item 3, you should see the list the item 2.

Do not know how to do the SQL query, I guess first I have to get the IDs of all users who recommended the article being viewed, and later, check the ID of items most repeated among the selected user IDs.

And then with those IDs of the items, get the item title or author information.

But I have no idea how to make the SQL query in a more optimized way. I would appreciate your supports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I splitted your problem into 2 tasks:

1.Select all the users, that recommended this item except the current user:

```
SELECT
    recommendations.user
FROM
    recommendations
WHERE
    recommendations.item=$item_id
AND
    recommendations.user!=$user_id
```

2.Then we use this query as a subquery to get all the items, recommended by those users, except the currently viewed item:

```
SELECT
    items.id,
    items.title
FROM
    items
INNER JOIN
    recommendations
ON
    items.id=recommendations.item
WHERE
    recommendations.user IN
(
SELECT
    recommendations.user
FROM
    recommendations
WHERE
    recommendations.item=$item_id
AND
    recommendations.user!=$user_id
)
AND
    items.id!=$item_id
GROUP BY
    items.id
```

3.If you want to show the most recommended items first, you'll need to sort the results by number of users, who recommended the item:

```
SELECT
    items.id,
    items.title,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
    items
INNER JOIN
    recommendations
ON
    items.id=recommendations.item
WHERE
    recommendations.user IN
(
SELECT
    recommendations.user
FROM
    recommendations
WHERE
    recommendations.item=$item_id
AND
    recommendations.user!=$user_id
)
AND
    items.id!=$item_id
GROUP BY
    items.id
ORDER BY
    cnt DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot, but how do I show the items most recommended at the beginning of the list, as I sort by number of recommendations... or what you think?

Comment: Thanks for this. How can we show recommended items to anonymous users?

In other words, if User1 recommends items A,B,C,D; user2 recommends items A,C and User3 recommends A,C,D etc., I have to show C,D,B items to the users who are not logged in and watching item A.

Comment: @NareshKumar It's late here. I'll look into your question and answer tomorrow.

Comment: @NareshKumar What is the formal rule for recommended items to be shown?

Comment: I have got the solution. When a customer watching item 1("Hello"), we have to use following query:

    SELECT i.title, i.author, count( i.id ) AS cnt
    FROM recommendations r
    JOIN items i ON i.id = r.item
    WHERE user
    IN (
        SELECT user
        FROM recommendations
        WHERE item = '1'
    )
    AND r.item <> '1'
    GROUP BY item
    ORDER BY cnt DESC

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly accomplish your goal using Joins, but it might be a better idea to have a third table with a one to one relationship for each item and a corresponding recommended item.

This way your Mysql query for recommended items will be much more efficient querying this third table for the source item and returning a result set of all recommended items.

You can then also do a simple query to the recommendations table to get the ids of the people that recommended the items in question.

With small numbers of items, this may seem to be overkill, but as you approach large numbers, the optimization could be significant in the Mysql processing required.